# system of equations solving for positive $a,b,c$

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

i need help 
i need to find positive number $a,b,c$ solving this system of equations?

$$(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)=abc$$
$$a+b+c=1$$
I found that $0<a,b,c<1$ and I try to solve it by try $(1-a)=a$, $(1-b)=b$ and $(1-c)=c$ and got that 
$a=0.5,b=0.5,c=0.5$ but it contradicts the second equations.

Can someone help me?

Comment: If any two of $a, b, c$ are zero, with the third equal to $1$, both equations are satisfied: so $0 \lt a, b, c \lt 1$ are not correct "strict" bounds.

Comment: As the tag wiki of [tag:systems-of-equations] told, the [tag:systems-of-equations] tag cannot be used as the only tag for the question.

Answer (score 1):

by expanding the left hand side you will have
$$1-(a+b+c)+ab+bc+ac-abc=abc
$$
using the second equality we will have:
$$2abc=ab+bc+ca
$$
And using the substitution method we can replace $a$ by $1-(b+c)$ then we have:
$$2bc(1-(b+c))=(1-(b+c))(b+c)+bc
$$
$$\Rightarrow 2bc-2b^2c-2bc^2=b+c-b^2-c^2-2bc+bc
$$
$$\Rightarrow 2b^2c+2bc^2+b+c-b^2-c^2-3bc=0 \qquad s.t. \quad 0 \leq b,c \leq 1
$$

Answer (score 1):

If any two of $a,b,c$ are zero, with the third equal to $1$, both equations are satisfied: so $0<a,b,c<1$ are not correct "strict" bounds.

So we have the following three solutions for $(a, b, c)$:

- $(1, 0, 0)$
- $(0, 1, 0)$
- $(0, 0, 1)$

You have a degree three equation: $(1 - a)(1-b)(1 - c)=abc$, and a linear (degree 1) equation: $a + b + c = 1,\;$ so we can rest with our three solutions.

Answer (score 0):

From $(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)=abc$ you cannot deduce $(1-a)=1$ and so on.  One set of solutions is to make both sides zero-let $a=1,b=0,c=0$ or any permutation.  The symmetry means that any permutation of a solution will also be a solution.  Given one cubic and one linear equation you expect three solutions and we have that many.

Answer (score 0):

I get that there are no solutions to the equations.
Here is my reasoning:

Since
$(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)=abc$,
substituting
$c = 1-a-b$
we get
$(1-a)(1-b)(a+b)=ab(1-a-b)$
.

Multiplying,
$(1-a-b+ab)(a+b) = ab - a^2b-ab^2$
or
$a+b-a^2-2ab-b^2+a^2b+ab^2= ab - a^2b-ab^2$
or
$a+b-a^2-b^2-3ab+2a^2b+2ab^2 = 0$.

Write this as a quadratic in $b$.

$\begin{align}
0 
&=b^2(2a-1)+b(2a^2-3a+1) -a^2+a\\
&=b^2(2a-1)+b(2a-1)(a-1)-a(a-1)\\
\end{align}
$.

The discriminant
is

$\begin{align}
D 
&= d^2\\ 
&= ((2a-1)(a-1))^2+4a(a-1)(2a-1)\\
&= (2a-1)(a-1)((2a-1)(a-1)+4a)\\
&= (2a-1)(a-1)(2a^2+a+1)\\
\end{align}
$

Since $0 < a < 1$
(by assumption),
$a-1<0$
so
if $D > 0$
we must have
$2a-1 < 0$
or
$a < 1/2$.

Since
$(2a-1)(a-1)
= 2a^2-3a+1
< 2a^2+a+1
$,
$0 < ((2a-1)(a-1))^2 < d^2 < (2a^2+a+1)^2$
or
$(1-2a)(1-a)=2a^2-3a+1 < d < 2a^2+a+1$

The roots are

$\begin{align}
b
& = \dfrac{-(2a-1)(a-1)\pm d}{2(2a-1)}\\
& = \dfrac{(1-2a)(1-a)\mp d}{2(1-2a)}\\
& = \dfrac{1-a}{2}\mp\dfrac{ d}{2(1-2a)}\\
\end{align}
$

Let $r = \dfrac{ d}{2(1-2a)}$,
so the roots are
$b_1 = \dfrac{1-a}{2}+r$
and
$b_2 = \dfrac{1-a}{2}-r$
.

Since $d > (1-2a)(1-a)$,
$r 
> \dfrac{ (1-2a)(1-a)}{2(1-2a)}
= \dfrac{ 1-a}{2}
$,
so $b_2 < 0$ and connot be a solution.

The last thing we need to
see is if 
we can choose $a$ so that
$ b_1 < 1$.

This means that
$\dfrac{1-a}{2}+\dfrac{ d}{2(1-2a)}< 1
$
or
$(1-a)(1-2a)+ d< 2(1-2a)$
or

$\begin{align}
 d
&< 2(1-2a)-(1-a)(1-2a)\\
&=2-4a-(1-3a+2a^2)\\
&=1-a-2a^2\\
&=(1-2a)(1+a)\\
\end{align}
$.

Since
$d^2 = (2a-1)(a-1)(2a^2+a+1)
= (1-2a)(1-a)(2a^2+a+1)
$,
we want
$(1-2a)(1-a)(2a^2+a+1)
< ((1-2a)(1+a))^2
$
or
$(1-a)(2a^2+a+1)
< (1-2a)(1+a)^2
=(1-2a)(1+2a+a^2)
$
or
$1+a^2-2a^3 < 1-2a^2-2a^3$
or
$3a^2 < 0$.

But this can never hold,
so there are no solutions
satisfying the equations.

Comment: why $2a-1$ is always $>0?$

Comment: To have real roots, the discriminant must be positive. It has the product $(2a-1)(a-1)$. Since $a < 1$, $a-1 < 0$, so $2a-1 < 0 $ also to make the product positive.

Answer (score 0):

There are no positive $a$, $b$, $c$ that satisfy your equations.

*Proof.* Let 
$$\sigma_1:=a+b+c,\quad \sigma_2:=ab+bc+ca,\quad \sigma_3:=abc\ .$$
Then your two equations are equivalent to
$$ \sigma_1=1\qquad\wedge\qquad \sigma_2=2\sigma_3\ .$$ It follows that the three numbers $a$, $b$, $c$ would have to be the solutions of an equation of the form
$$f(t):=t^3-t^2+2pt-p=0$$
for some $p>0$. To enable three real zeros of $f$ the derivative $f'(t)=3t^2-2t+2p$ would have to have two real zeros
$$t_i={2\pm\sqrt{4-24 p}\over 6}\qquad(i=1,\>2)\ ,$$
which requires $0<p\leq{1\over6}$. In addition it would be necessary that the the values $f(t_1)$ and $f(t_2)$ have opposite sign. Computation gives
$$f(t_1)\>f(t_2)={1\over27}p(4-13p+32p^2)\ ,$$
and this cannot be negative when $p>0$.